# How can i Concatenate memory blocks

Tags: arrays, c, memory

I need a requirement where in i need to Concatenate memory blocks
I'm sending my data from UDP as chunks of 100 bytes, and i have verified the transfer, but when I send a 800 bytes array as 8 chunks, and Concatenate them to an array I'm not able to retrieve data

im sending an int array of 200 elements which comes to 800 bytes and the first element is being incremented to check data

my simple logic goes like this

```
        // allocate memory for main memory block
        void* rcv_Data = malloc(800);

       // allocate memory for chunk memory block 
        void* tempdata = malloc(100);

       // read all 8 chunks 
       for (int ndx=0; ndx<8;ndx++)
       {
        Read_packet(skt,tempdata,100);
        memmove((rcv_Data +(ndx*100)) ,tempdata, 100);
       }

        
        printf("data  is %d\n",((int*)rcv_Data )[0]);
```

but my data being printed is 0 all time , but actual data is a incrementing number

my read function is as follows

```
    int Read_packet(int CSPL_Socket, void *buf,int datalen)
{
    int numb_bytes=0;
    numb_bytes=read(CSPL_Socket, buf, datalen);
                        if(numb_bytes<0)
                        {
                            CSPL_SOK_ERROR(-6);
                            close(CSPL_Socket);
                            exit(1);
                            return -1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //printf("Count %d\n",numb_bytes);
                        }
    return 0;
}
```

i have just posted small portion of code , just not to make it too long and complicate, i need advice on whether this logic is correct or not

Comment: *i have just posted small portion of code*. All questions seeking debugging help on Stack Overflow must post a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, have you done basic debugging such as determining whether `read` data is even correct before any copying of data around?

Comment: i have verified the data using Wireshark  my doubt is mainly on using memmove with pointers

Comment: wireshark is not your program. You need to verify that your program is reading the right data in the first place. Please provide a complete minimal reproducible example for further help.